# Using “Of” or “For” in My Paper’s Title

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, grammaticality

I would like to consult with you regarding the wording of a title for a recent paper of mine. Specifically, the question is whether to use "of" or "for". In order to keep it simple and maintain some anonymity I will use examples that are similar to my actual title, hoping that doesn't change the question too much.

My title is something similar to, say, "A Tight Distance Bound of Fuzzy Pairings." However, my advisor thinks it sounds unnatural, and suggested using "A Tight Distance Bound for Fuzzy Pairings" instead.

I agree that "A Tight Bound for" is better than "A Tight Bound of" if it is followed by the name of a known problem or by an objective, such as "Approximating the Distance of Fuzzy Pairings." However, this is not exactly the case here. Moreover, I feel like "A Tight Bound on the Distance of Fuzzy Pairings" is good, and in some sense my title simply shortens it. What do you think?

If I try to simplify further, I guess the imporant part is "A Distance Bound" of/for objects for which distance is defined.

Comment: I'd use .........: a tight bound

Comment: Since you're not giving us the *actual* title of your paper, could you not provide a less "jargonny" version here that still illustrates the possible preposition choice between ***of*** and ***for***? It's difficult to think in terms of syntax when the actual *words* are so domain-specific as to be all but unintelligible to the average Anglophone.

Comment: Your advisor is correct.

Comment: I'd suggest you listen to your advisor. Paper titles are expected to fit certain formats and match certain conventions. Insofar as I can guess at your subject, "for" sounds more usual (compare "a limit for X") and you don't really seem to have expressed a coherent reason why it is wrong.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This could be somewhat problematic because I may then unintentially present a biased example, it's hard to keep the preposition choice exactly the same. My example given above is in fact very similar to my actual title. If I try to simplify further, I guess the imporant part is "Distance Bound" of/for objects for which distance is defined.

Comment: I think what that amounts to is that this is a ***domain-specific*** enquiry, which should perhaps be asked on a maths / geometry / statistics subsite within Stack Exchange. In any case, titles for "science" papers don't necessarily reflect mainstream Anglophone usage today. So as others have already suggested, you should probably give more weight to your advisor's perspective in this matter.

Comment: Also review other related papers and see how they form the terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer assuming that that is the *actual* title of your paper, since... well, since there isn't much else I can do!

That said: the short answer is that your supervisor is right - "for" is better than "of" here.

You're right that "A tight bound on the distance of fuzzy pairings" is good - but you can't shorten that to "*A tight distance bound of fuzzy pairings". That's because you're changing what the preposition refers to - in the first it's "*distance* of fuzzy pairings"; in the second it's "*bound* (of/for) fuzzy pairings". And we don't generally say "a tight bound of <the thing bounded>" - either "a tight bound *on* (the specific measurement that is bounded)", or "a tight bound *for* (the problem or situation requiring a bound)". [A search in Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22a+tight+bound%22&btnG=) confirms this.

(The phrase "a tight bound of ..." is usually followed by the bound itself - for example, O(n²) - and if you [search for it](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22a+tight+bound+of%22&btnG=) the vast majority of examples are that; the few that have "a tight bound of <something>" are, on reading them, not written by native speakers and contain many other errors too.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please clarify one thing: you said that "A tight bound for" is followed by the problem or situation requiring a bound, but here it is followed by simply the name of a mathematical object (and there's "Distance" before bound.) Is this still OK?

Also, what do you think of "A Tight Distance Bound for Fuzzy Pairings" compared to "A tight bound on the distance of fuzzy pairings"? Is one better than the other?

Comment: @Nathan: Yes it's OK to have just the name of the object (assuming people will understand from context what the bound is for). Personally I prefer the longer title, but the shorter one is OK if you need to be concise.